# Remove last 3 characters from strings if they fit specific pattern in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my data frame, I have a lot of sting values in `Column A` that are very inconsistent.

One thing I want to do is that if the last 3 characters fit a specific pattern of a dash (-) followed by two numbers, I would like to remove the dash and two numbers.

So something like:

`2X-VA-0561001-SBJ02-NI-01` would become `2X-VA-0561001-SBJ02-NI`

Something like:

`A.2-FW-74174-KB02-0000232-HT` would remain the same

I'd ideally like to create a new column `Column B` to put these new values, keeping `Column A`

I think something like this would work, based on something I've done previously, but I can quite figure it out:

`df['Column B'] = df['Column A'].str.replace(r'SOMETHING GOES HERE', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex `-\d{2}$` - `\d{2}` is for match 2 digits and `$` for end of strings:

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column A'].str.replace(r'-\d{2}$', '', regex=True)   
print (df)
                       Column A                      Column B
0     2X-VA-0561001-SBJ02-NI-01        2X-VA-0561001-SBJ02-NI
1  A.2-FW-74174-KB02-0000232-HT  A.2-FW-74174-KB02-0000232-HT
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. That's worked.